# Java write objects into CSV file

Tags: java, java-8

I have a requirement where I have to write list of objects into CSV file. I cannot do

```
ObjectOutputStream.write()
```

As I also need to put some additional attributes along with object data, and have to remove couple of fields from object to write into CSV file.
Please guide me a better way to do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net), follow an [OpenCSV tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv) perhaps, and have at it :)

NB: There isn't really a good option to tell java: "Just write this object" without any context. Just write code that explicitly sends each field. So, don't do (psuedocode):

```
csv.write(object);
```

but do:

```
csv.writeEntry(object.name, formatDate(object.birthDate));
```

This way, you decide the ordering, the way each field is formatted, and you can add or skip whatever you want to.